# C, small int to larger uint conversion

Tags: c

When converting from a small int (negative value) to a larger uint what should the value be?
Example:

```
int8_t small_int = 0x80;
uint16_t big_uint = (uint16_t)small_int;   // result should be 0xFF80 or 0x0080?
```

I was expecting 0x80, from the C standard like this:
[image]

0x80 + 0xFFFF = 0x0079,
then add 1 gives 0x0080.

But my simulator gives the result for big_uint as 0xFF80.
I tried this for 8 => 16, 16 => 32 and 32 => 64. All come out the same (i.e. sign extended)
Is this because the compiler actually does this:

```
uint16_t big_uint = (uint16_t)((int16_t)small_int);
```

If so could someone clarify what 6.3.1.3 part 2 actually means with a simple example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int8_t` is a two’s complement type, so the bits 10000000 in it represent −128.

For `uint16_t`, one more than the maximum value that can be represented in `uint16_t` is one more than 65,535 (hexadecimal FFFF), which is 65,536 (hexadecimal 10000).

−128 plus 65,536 is 65,408, which is FF80 in hexadecimal.

Backing up, though, there is a problem in your first declaration: `int8_t small_int = 0x80;`. `int8_t` can represent values from −128 to +127. But `0x80` represents the value 128. It does not fit. When it is used to initialize an `int8_t`, a conversion is performed. Per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, the conversion is implementation-defined (when converting an unrepresentable value to a signed integer type). It is common for compilers to wrap modulo the number of values representable in the type (256), but this is not guaranteed by the C standard. Properly, your definition should be `int8_t small_int = -128;` or `int8_t small_int = -0x80;`.

Answer (score 1):

The value 0x80, stored in a signed 8 bit int, has a value of -128. So the new value is the old value -128, repeatedly adding 0x10000, giving 0xff80.

There is no intermediate conversion to int16_t. It’s not needed. The adding is done with the real mathematical values.

Comment: Thanks gnasher. Should have realised the "Value" is -128, not 0x80  = +128.